# Multiplicative functions into integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $D$ be an integral domain and $f : \mathbb{Z}^+ \rightarrow D$ a nonzero multiplicative function. Prove that
$\sum_ {d\mid n} \mu(d)f(d) = \sum_{
p\mid n}(1-f(p))$ (where $p$ is prime).

I tried this with $n=8$ and I get 
$$ f(1)-f(2)+f(4)-f(8) = 1-f(2)$$

I want to prove this, but I can't see  how to calculate it. $f(m)\in D$ , how does that help in the calculation?  Thanks in advanced ^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure your formula is right? I think you meant:
$$\sum_{d\mid n} \mu (d) f(d)=\prod_{p\mid n} (1-f(p))$$

If so, this is a consequence of the following more general identity: let $n=p_1^{\alpha_1}\ldots p_r^{\alpha_r}$ (where each $p_i$ is prime), and let $g(n)$ be a multiplicative function. Consider $G(n)=\sum_{d\mid n} g(d)$. Then $G(n)$ satisfies the following identity:
$$G(n)=\prod_{i=1}^r (1+g(p_i)+g(p_i^2)+\ldots+g(p_i^{\alpha_i}))$$

This is easy to check, and we can use it when $g(n)=\mu (n) f(n)$. Note that in this case $g(p^k)=0$ for every $k\ge 2$ and $p$ prime. Also, $g(1)=f(1)$ and $g(p)=-f(p)$. Therefore, we get:
$$\sum_{d\mid n} \mu (d) f(d)=\prod_{p\mid n} (1-f(p))$$